# Does the close() system call close all references to the file?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, pipe, system-calls, file-descriptor

Let's say we have a pipe, `my_pipe`, which occupies file descriptors at entries 3 and 4 of the process's FDT ([initial FDT scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1UuA.png))

1. First, we close the stdout standard output stream using `close(1)` ([updated FDT scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLplR.png)).
2. Next, using `dup(my_pipe[1])`, we create a copy of the pipe's writing end file descriptor at the lowest available FDT entry - in our case entry 1, which was made available in the previous step.
   `my_pipe[1]` is now referred to by both entry 1 and entry 4 ([updated FDT scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnU8u.png)).
3. The following command we run is `close(my_pipe[1])`.

My question is - which of the file descriptors referring to `my_pipe[1]` will close?

Comment: You have read documentation for `close`, haven't you? From [man close](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html): "`close()` closes a file descriptor, so that it no longer refers to any file and may be reused.". That is, `close` closes primarily only a file descriptor, so others file descriptors referred to the same file remain usable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, of course I've read it. If the line was `close(4)` or `close(1)` it would've been clear to me which entry will close. I'm confused because in this case `my_pipe[1]` was passed as the parameter instead of an FDT index. As I've shown, `my_pipe[1]`  is referred to by two file descriptors - the original at entry 4, and the copy at entry 1, so it seems very ambiguous to me which of the two is supposed to close.
I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Well, it seems you want to understand interoperability between `dup` and `close`. In short, `dup` creates a **new** file descriptor, which is **separated** from the **old** one from the view of `close`. So, even in your case `1` becomes a duplicate of `4`, `close(4)` doesn't close ``1``. (Since value of `my_pipe[1]` is 4, then `close(my_pipe[1])` is processed as `close(4)`).

Comment: That last sentence in the brackets made everything clear!
Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: After a successful `dup` the original fd and returned fd both refer to the same, underlying _open file description_. The _open file description_ will not be released until both file descriptors are closed. It's actually more complicated than that because `fork` effectively duplicates the parent's file descriptors into the child. Also, closing a file descriptor does not invalidate any non-anonymous `mmap` operations performed on the file descriptor, so those also get references to the _open file description_.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5284062/1216776